# Queries to connect Azure Websites with SQL server in Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I had one requirements to migrate 1 web application and couples of databases (4) to windows azure. I had selected SQL Server standard edition to move all databases and moved my databases to sql server VM on windows azure by taking backup & restore.
**1)** Is there any other method to migrate to sql server VM from on premises sql server?

I had selected Windows Azure websites to move web application so

**2)** How can i connect above DBs to this website? Do i need to follow same steps like normal sql server by opening TCP port along with Mixed mode authentication?
**3)** I think i do no need to create affinity group here because only 1 VM is there?
**4)** In my web application i had used telerik controls so would it work in Windows Azure websites or Do I need to choose separate windows server on 2nd VM and follow installation step as did in normal server?

**5)** In SQl server VM size display 127GB (os disk) so price of storage will be included in SQL server price or it will be calculated separately?
 
**6)** How can i take benefit of Virtual Network in above scenario?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can simply backup your databases and restore them onto the VM's SQL Server

2) Yes.

3) Correct.

4) Telerik controls are client controls and should have no bearing on your server-side deployment platform

5) OS space on the VM is part of the price of the VM's hourly fee

6) What are you looking to do with virtual network?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 6) I am looking for some secure way (using corporate identity) to connect sql server instead of Mixed mode authentication.

Comment: Gotcha, than the answer is yes.  You can setup a private network between your AD and the VM in the cloud and connect to SQL server using your AD credentials

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Q.1:

With **MSSQL Server 2014**, it's very simple to do that using SSMS. Simply right-click on selected database and choose "Deploy Database to Windows Azure VM".

See image below:

[image]

With **SQL Server 2012**, one can deploy to Azure SQL but not on VM.